# Ruby on Rails: How to update instance attributes inside the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Hi I am working on a rails project and I have an scheduler object. I want to set a method inside the instance to automatically update the next_due attribute to be the upcoming due date. All schedules occur daily for simplicity. I have seeded the scheduler so every instance has a next_due value.

Below is my code and it does not seem working.

```
class ScheduledTask < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :next_due

  def self.update_next_due
    while next_due < DateTime.now
      next_due += 1.day
    end
  end  
end
```

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How and where you are calling method `update_next_due` ?

Comment: Yes. U saved me. Thanks.